# How to make masonry Grid on portfolio module DIVI

Tags: wordpress, layout, grid

I am new to Wordpress and Divi,

How do I achieve the masonry grid layout using Divi builder with portfolio module? Similar to this grid layout used here: http://buck.tv/#/work/featured

I am using Divi 3.0 version, I have got this far http://maninjawebs.com/explore/index.php/portfolio/ using Divi builder. I appreciate any kind of advise.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you've made a start with some code but it doesn't work for you. Can you create an [mcve] of your site so we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I only added code on stylesheet.css to show text and logo when you hover, and it worked. all its good now for getting the mansory layout, see here: http://maninjawebs.com/explore/index.php/port/

Thank you.

Comment: Please add your minimal code example _into the post itself_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively use shortcode in your page using divi builder after creating & selecting masonry grid in 3rd party  protfolio plugin.  you may try

https://wordpress.org/plugins/portfolio-x/

or
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/portfolios/
or
https://wordpress.org/plugins/portfolio-gallery/

Thank you!

Comment: Hi your recommendation didn't seem to work for me, however it pointed me to the right direction. I used:
https://codecanyon.net/item/jb-portfolio-a-lightweight-portfolio-plugin-for-wordpress/19381634
with shortcode, see here: http://maninjawebs.com/explore/index.php/port/

Thank you.

Comment: Great! glad to here that my alternative way give a solution.